# Removing ::after pseudo-element's content from the last span element

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to remove the content of `::after` pseudo-element from the last `<span>` element. I've managed to do it okay with the others but I'm not sure why this one isn't working properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/L6d6w1ys/

HTML:

```
<section class="comments">
                <h3>Comments:</h3>
                    <div class="radius panel">
                        <div class="comment-meta">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-3 columns">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
                                </div>
                                <div class="large-9 columns">
                                    <span>User 1</span>  <span>Date: 19/10/2014</span>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam veritatis cupiditate soluta qui, numquam laudantium fugit! Cum reiciendis sapiente doloremque molestiae laudantium quas aut, itaque rerum minus natus sed.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

CSS:

```
 .comments {
            p , span{
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .comment-meta span{
                &:after{
                    content: " | ";
                    margin:0 15px;
                }
                &:last-child:after{
                    content: " ";
                    margin: 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the [`span:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) selector won't select any `<span>` element.

Assuming the markup, **no** `<span>` element is the *last child* of its parent.

Try using [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead:

```css
.comments {
  p , span{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .comment-meta span {
        &:after {
            content: " | ";
            margin:0 15px;
        }
        &:last-of-type:after {
            content: none;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
}
```